# 'Fardée comme elle l'était': why a definite article?

Tags: articles

From Blaise Cendrars' story 'Le Saint Inconnu' (1937):

> Fardée comme elle l'était pour se rendre au bal nègre et habillée de l'une des dernières robes de Paul Poiret, cette belle femme [...] n'avait pas d'âge'.

I am just wondering why it's 'comme elle l'était' and not just 'comme elle était'. Is this use of the definite article grammatically necessary or stylistically optional?

Comment: **The pronoun avoids repeating the adjective intelligente.** However, it is not necessary. c) Adj. + comme + prop. attributive.Intelligente comme elle est, intelligente comme elle l'est. Intelligente comme elle est intelligente : TFLi As intelligent as she was v. As intelligent as she was intelligent

Comment: @Lambie You are not dealing simply with a plain adjective; it is not "fardée" but "fardée pour se rendre au Bal Nègre"; this is not the same type of adjectival phrase. I believe that in this case, the verb "être" does not have this property of being a proform; a pronoun is ncessary in French.

Comment: *fardée comme elle l'était* follows the exact form given in the TFLi: *Intelligente comme elle l'est*. So, no, it isn't required but is more elegant in French for the reason given in my first comment.

Comment: @Lambie Elegance at the price of otioseness makes for little elegance but instead for showy frivolity.

Comment: I cannot understand half of what you write. There is nothing hateful (otiose) about citing a French dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie **otiose** : having no practical function, superfluous (SOED).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the définite article, but instead the personal pronoun "le". It is put here for "fardée". This could have been written "fardée comme elle était fardée" and it would have the same meaning. The grammatical function of "le" is "attribut du sujet « elle »".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/le/1))     LE, LA, LES, pronom. obj. dir.
> I. − [Le est uniquement lié au verbe qu'il précède ou qu'il suit le plus immédiatement]
> B. − [Le est attribut du suj.]
> ♦ C'est un vrai paysan du Danube, et ravi de **l**'être (Bremond, Hist. sent. relig., t. 4, 1920, p. 495).
> ♦ Martyrisé par les mouches, il se disait que les taureaux **l**'étaient encore beaucoup plus que lui, ce qui lui permit enfin d'aimer son mal (Montherl., Bestiaires,1926, p. 527).
> ♦ Vanité de ce cri d'homme du désert! Vous êtes tels que si vous l'aperceviez comme moi, vous ne pourriez plus **l**'être (G. Bataille, Exp. int.,1943, p. 82)
> ♦ Si je ne craignais d'être impoli, je vous dirais tout cru que vous me semblez en démence. − Je **le** semblerais à beaucoup d'autres, monsieur. Borel, Champavert,1833, p. 191.

---

*Correction after user Guillaume31's comment (see comment section)*

The use of this pronoun is not  necessary, but still, it is not a stylistic device, and both forms seem to be usable in everyday speech. However, in the given sentence, it seems that it is necessary. The removal of this pronoun could yield another interpretation. One could say that without the pronoun "comme elle était" means "as she was", "without any other sort of prepartion" such as a particular hairdo, or without preliminary washing. I believe that preseving the pronoun permits to avoid any misunderstanding.

After some reflection, it occurred to me that the necessity of this pronoun is dictated by the necessity of an "attribut du sujet" in the subordinate "comme … nègre"; the clause "comme elle était  pour se rendre au bal nègre" would not be complete. If the verb "to be" can be a proform in English in that contexte, this is not the case in French.

- Fardée comme elle l'était pour se rendre au bal nègre et habillée de l'une des dernières robes de Paul Poiret, cette belle femme [...] n'avait pas d'âge'.
- Heavily made up, as she was when she went to

*Ex.*

- — Elle était rapide.
  — Elle l'était, c'est vrai, mais pas toujours. (*The pronoun can't be omited.*)
  — She was fast. — She was, but not always.

Comment: TLFi disagrees on the last part: c) Adj. + comme + prop. attributive. *Intelligente comme elle est*, intelligente comme elle l'est. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme

Comment: @guillaume31 Wouldn't you think that a different interpretation is possible if the pronoun is omitted?

Comment: aside from language level - colloquial vs slightly more formal with the pronoun, not that I can see. Are you thinking of something specific?

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes, I tried to explain it in my answer. It would be "comme elle était" as in "Elle s'est présentée à la directrice comme elle était, avec une blouse déchirée et ses cheveux ébouriffés, car elle n'avait pas eu le temps de se changer."

Comment: I don't see it making much sense, "fardée" and "comme elle était" as you define it being quite paradoxical - heavily made up but natural? However I agree that in that specific sentence, *fardée comme elle était pour...* reads slightly odd. My remark was more about the general use of the pronoun in that context.

Comment: @guillaume31 No, not "heavily made up but natural", rather "made up, but just made up and not showing  any of the usual appearances that go along with make-up, that is no hairdo, not manicured, without adornments, and possibly not even washed".

Comment: It would seem a bit far fetched and not well connected to "pour se rendre" but why not, fair point.

Comment: @guillaume31 Ibelieve that you are right on that count.

Comment: If you translate this as heavily made up, one wonders how she can be a belle femme. heavily made up is negatively connoted in English. And there is the verb to fard in English. How can the pronoun not be necessary and also not be a stylistic device?

Comment: Farded as she was to attend the *Bal nègre*: There can't be a comma in that.

Comment: @Lambie "Belle femme" hardly refers to apperances as manifested by extrinsic signs of embellishment, but on the contrary to the the person herself, considering the plainest apparel in which her appearance can be so asserted. So, une "belle feme" can be wearing tasteless dresses and showy make-up (but it'll occur to most observers that this is far from  being the rule, as the Americans say, pretty is pretty does.).

Comment: @Lambie Read the example that I provided; there is no question of stylas concerns that example, yet, in French there is a necessity for the personal pronoun. Don't you know that?

Comment: Your English translation is **wrong**: Heavily made up, as she was when she went to. So is: asserting an appearance.

Comment: @Lambie 1/ https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/farde 2/  "so" is made to replace "to be a 'belle femme'" :  I think that is obvious.

Comment: Farded as she was to attend the Bal Nègre and dressed in one of Paul Poiret's latest designs, this beautiful woman [...] was ageless.