# L'emploi du pronom personnel neutre « le » en fonction d'attribut et la proposition commençant avec « comme » etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, pronoms-personnels, antécédent, attributs

Il s'agit d'une demande de précision de l'emploi du pronom neutre *le* en fonction d'attribut suite à une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50665/26366). Selon la nature de l'antécédent ou du déterminant qui le précède etc., on a parfois le pronom qui s'accorde en genre et d'autres où on a le pronom neutre :

> Je passe ici pour *votre* maîtresse, [...] mais je ne LA suis point
> (HUGO, *Angelo*, 1,1) [fém., *la maîtresse*]
>  Ma sœur est *une*
> enfant, - et je ne LE suis plus (MUSSET, *A quoi rêvent les j.
> filles*, 1,3). [neutre]

Mais une chose est certaine dans ces deux cas-là, c'est que le pronom est requis sinon on se retrouve avec essentiellement une affirmation de non-existence.

Dans d'autres cas le pronom est optionnel. Dans le *Bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §673... R3, voir aussi 218, 1141) on trouve une affirmation à l'effet que « le pronom *le* est facultatif dans les propositions introduites par *comme* et dans les propositions corrélatives amenées par *aussi*, *plus*, etc ».

Sauf que dans une autre question on a identifié une phrase (« Fardée comme elle l'était pour se rendre au bal nègre et habillée de l'une des dernières robes de Paul Poiret, cette belle femme debout dans la lumière du porche d'un luxueux palace de la rue Boissy-d'Anglas n'avait pas d'âge. », Cendrars, 1937) où l'on semble avoir une proposition introduite par comme avec un passif et un pronom qui réfère à un adjectif ou un participe passé ou un syntagme qui peut être assimilé à un attribut, mais on sent qu'on aurait besoin dans ce cas du pronom, mais pas de la même manière qu'avec les deux exemples qui précèdent. Et une particularité c'est que l'adjectif auquel on réfère est précisé par un complément introduit avec la préposition *pour* et référant possiblement à une action passée ou participant à un haut degré ou autrement.

---

S'agit-il d'une exception à une exception d'une nuance de l'emploi des formes conjointes du pronom ou de quelque chose de plus fondamental ? Peut-on brièvement analyser la phrase et expliquer pourquoi et comment au juste se fait-il que l'affirmation au LBU ne puisse être appliquée ici : est-ce le sens ou la syntaxe/l'usage qui exige le pronom neutre ici, est-ce la préposition pour et les tournures qui y sont associées qui le justifie, y a-t-il d'autres contraintes qui empêchent l'exception de s'appliquer (et donc d'avoir le sens voulu sans le pronom) ou qui nécessitent d'avoir le pronom ?

Answer (score 1):

À mon avis ce pronom est nécessaire parce que s'il manque il n'y a aucun moyen d'associer automatiquement (facilement) « fardée » à « pour se rendre au bal nègre ».

- Fardée comme elle (l')était, on ne pouvait pas lui donner d'âge.
- Intelligent comme il (l')était, il n'avait aucune chance de faire carrière dans cette activité.

Dans ces phrases, « fardé comme elle (l')était » signifie « (étant) donnée la manière dont elle était fardée/ », « (étant) donné son niveau d'intelligence » ; l'omission de l'article est concevable, d'autant plus que le sens est celui d'une expression idiomatique. Cependant, lorsque la forme verbale « était »  a un attribut qui n'est plus entièrement énoncé dans ce qui précède, il doit être énoncé dans cette subordonnée.

- Fardée || comme | elle | était | **fardée pour se rendre au bal nègre**…
- Fardée | comme elle **l**'était  **pour se rendre au bal nègre**…

Ce qui rend le pronom nécessaire, à mon avis, c'est l'incertitude qui résulte du fait que l'attribut se construit en combinant un élément déduit à partir d'une propriété de proforme qu'a le verbe (« fardée » avec un élément explicite dans la subordonnée (« pour se rendre au bal nègre »). Le processus serait trop complexe pour être [identifié/mis en pratique] facilement et on se trouve devant l'indécision de devoir attribuer une signification propre à  « comme elle était pour se rendre au bal nègre » ; cela peut ne pas se faire très vite, prendre un certain temps. DAns tous les cas, utiliser le pronom relèverait d'un meilleur style, d'un meilleur français.

1/ On voit par exemple que dans le cas « [émue comme elle l'était](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9mue+comme+elle+l%27%C3%A9tait%2C%C3%A9mue+comme+elle+%C3%A9tait&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9mue%20comme%20elle%20l%27%20%C3%A9tait%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A9mue%20comme%20elle%20l%27%20%C3%A9tait%3B%2Cc0) » le cas d'omission du pronom ne se trouve pas.

2/ Il y a le cas suivant, qui montre que ce processus pourrait peut-être se faire, mais il est unique.

- ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rapide%20comme%20il%20%C3%A9tait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) Cependant, ils ne se doutaient pas que Hélios, le père de la magicienne, était lui aussi à la recherche des sept saphirs du ciel et que rapide comme il était pour passer inaperçu, il aurait eu vite fait de se rendre sur leurs traces

3/ En ce qui concerne « vaillant comme il est » (vaillant comme il l'est » ne se trouve pas), on constate quil n'est jamais fait appel au processus de combinaison. ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vaillant%20comme%20il%20est%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

4/ « Triste comme elle l'est » est toujours la forme utilisée lorsque l'attribut n'est pas simple. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=triste+comme+elle+l%27est%2Ctriste+comme+elle+est&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctriste%20comme%20elle%20l%27%20est%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctriste%20comme%20elle%20est%3B%2Cc0)), [réf. 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22triste%20comme%20elle%20est%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), [réf. 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22triste%20comme%20elle%20l%27est%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

5/ On ne trouve que « paresseux comme il est », et en assez grand nombre, cependant pas une seules des occurrences n'est autre qu'un cas de déduction de l'attribut du fait seul de la propriété de proforme du verbe et donc toutes sont des cas du sens idiomatique. ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22paresseux%20comme%20il%20est%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

6/ On ne trouve que « menteur comme il est », et en assez grand nombre, cependant pas une seule des occurrences n'est autre qu'un cas de déduction de l'attribut du fait seul de la propriété de proforme du verbe et donc toutes sont des cas du sens idiomatique. ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22menteur%20comme%20il%20est%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

D'après les quelques vérifications faites semblerait se dessiner la tendance d'une omission du pronom presque seulement lorsque il est seul à contribuer à l'existence d'un attribut.

Comment: Merci ! En général, il n'y a conceptuellement cette rigidité de l'adéquation que devrait entretenir l'antécédent avec le pronom et qu'on voit souvent répétée en commentaire est qui est plus utile à l'apprenant en quête de certitude. Par exemple « _le_ pronom neutre ne représente pas exactement son antécédent, mais l'idée qui y est incluse ; il convient cependant de veiller à la clarté » (LBU). Par ailleurs des réductions, ellipses et différentes tournures existent sans s'appuyer sur une qualité « proforme » d'un verbe. Est-ce que ta dernière phrase veut dire l'équivalent d'avoir un attribut...

Comment: seul (fardée) par opposition à avoir un attribut qui comporte un complément ? Laquelle de tes affirmations reprend l'idée dont tu avais traité sur fardée par nature par opposition à fardée avec préparation ? Quelle serait la signification propre pour toi de « comme elle était pour se rendre au bal nègre ». Si on reconstruit la phrase en débutant par « Cette belle femme n'avait pas d'âge... » comme principale, est-on certain qu'on se trouve bien dans une proposition de la nature qu'on pense qu'elle a ? Je vais y penser.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa La dernière phrase a pour but de faire remarquer que l'omission est (apparemment) réservée aux cas où l'attribut est simple (il y a toujours un attribut avec le verbe « être »), c'est à dire entièrement recupérable à partir du pronom, et non le résultat d'une combinaison de ce que le pronom remplace et d'une addition que l'on trouverait dans la subordonnée. // Je le fais remarquer dans l'exemple unique que je relève, on pourrait trouver plus ou moins naturellement que « comme elle était pour se rendre au bal nègre » signifie « comme elle était _fardée_ pour se rendre  (1/2)

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa  au bal nègre » ; cependant, je trouve que cette interprétation n'est pas facilitée, alors que le pronom la rend immédiatement sans équivoque. Personnellement, je m'interroge et je ne suis pas bien sûr, jusqu'à j'en vienne à la conclusion que ce qu'il y a de plus logique est « comme elle était fardée pour … », seulement, j'ai dû faire un effort assez long et inutile que la simple addition d'un pronom supprime. (2/2)